# Break Singleton Using Serialization C#

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, singleton

This is my singletion class Person.

```
public class Person
{
    private static Person _person = null;

    private Person()
    { }

    public string Name { get; }

    public static Person PersonObj
    {
        get
        {
            if (_person == null)
                _person = new Person();

            return _person;
        }
    }
}
```

now i can create two instances of this class by Serialization.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person p = Person.PersonObj;
    string sss = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
    Person p1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(sss);    
    if (p != p1)
    {
           // insert here 
    }
}
```

Now after Serialization I have two different object. As the class is singleton how it can have two different objects ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A singleton is a programming concept - not a language feature. Its perfectly possible to create code that creates instances of classes that - in theory - should only be created by a singleton factory. You dont even need to use serialization to achieve that - just use `Activator.CreateInstance()`.

It might be helpful also to consider that your class constructor also doesn't have to get called; sure, if your call `new MyClass()` it will do, but deserialization doesn't have to call the constructor. Serialization as a concept stores and rehydrates the state of a class instance; so it doesn't need to obey other class instantiation concepts, like constructor scope or constructor logic.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have serialized the person object into a string, it breaks it's reference back to the original `Person p` object. In other words, the new string object has no knowledge of what it was before. When you Deserialize the string `sss` into a `Person` object, it's creating a new instance of that object. They may have the same value, but they are not the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

override private constructor using Reflection or implement ICloneable using MemberWiseClone() you can create two objects. But that is not recommended.

Answer (score -1):

They are not the same object reference. The default equality implementation is an instance compare. You need to override .Equals(obj) and compare fields for them to be the same.

Comment: I think you did not understand the question. This is what i am asking if class is singleton how it can have 2 objects ?

Comment: I see. Since you have a private ctor. I'm pretty sure Jason.net is able to instantiate objects even without a ctor. Most serialization has this capability. Json.Net is not using your PersonObj property.